# How to remove this strange folder in Mac?

Tags: macos

```
➜  var  pwd
/private/var
➜  var  sudo du -h -d 1 ./
  0B    .//agentx
  0B    .//at
 11M    .//audit
  0B    .//backups
1.3G    .//db
  0B    .//empty
1.4G    .//folders
  0B    .//folders~orig
  0B    .//jabberd
4.0K    .//lib
116M    .//log
  0B    .//mail
4.0K    .//msgs
  0B    .//netboot
1.9M    .//networkd
 30G    .//root
  0B    .//rpc
527M    .//run
  0B    .//rwho
204K    .//spool
  0B    .//tmp
1.0G    .//vm
  0B    .//yp
 35G    ./
```

The /private/var/root folder cost about 30GB and root user has not permission to access.Why did it still become bigger and bigger when normally using Mac and how to make it slim?

Comment: Try asking at apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/private/var/root is the root user's home directory.

[This AppleExaminer article](http://www.appleexaminer.com/MacsAndOS/Analysis/FolderLayout1/FolderLayout2/FolderLayout2.html) explains what each of the folders in /private/var are for.

The permissions for /private/var/root should be 750:

```
# ls -alh /private/var
...
drwxr-x---  11 root       wheel       374B Oct 19 15:26 root
...
```

Note that, when you are logged in as root and issue a pwd, you will get:

```
# pwd
/var/root
```

That's because /var is symlinked to /private/var:

```
$ ls -l /var
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 16  2014 /var -> private/var
```

It appears from your output that you can access /private/var/root just fine, or else du would have returned "Permission Denied" for that folder. :)

```
$ sudo su -
```

... will drop you directly into the root home directory -- as root -- and you can easily clean it up from there. :)

Comment: Thanks, I found it is a bug of Adobe installer which like a virus running with the system.F__k it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a system folder. I recommend you not to delete it :-) Use a cleaner software instead, to clean temporary files.